# Supporting "recursive objects" in lua

Tags: class, lua

I'm fairly new to lua and have the following problem with an assignment from a class:

We currently extend lua to support objects and inheritance. The Syntax for that is

```
Class{'MyClass', 
    attribute1 = String,
    attribute2 = Number
}

Class{'MySubClass', MyClass,
    attribute3 = Number
}
```

This works perfectly fine. The real problem lies within the next task: We should support "recursive types", that means a call like

```
Class{'MyClass', attribute = MyClass}
```

should result in an class with a field of the same type as the class. When this "class-constructor" is called the variable `MyClass` is `nil`, thats why the parameter table doesnt't have an entry `attribute`. How is it possible to access this attribute?

My first thought was using some kind of `nil`-table which gets returned every time the global `__index` is called with an unset key. This `nil`-table should behave like the normal `nil`, but can be checked for in the "class-constructor". The problem with this approach are comparisons like `nil == unknown`. This should return `true`, but as the `__eq` meta method of the `nil`-table is never called we cannot return `true`.

Is there another approach I'm currently just ignoring? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here the relevant part of the "testfile". The test by which the code is rated in class is another one and gets published later.

```
three = 3
print( three  == 3 , "Should be true")
print( unknown == nil , "Should be true" )

Class{'AClass', name = String, ref = AClass}
function AClass:write()
    print("AClass:write(), name of AClass:", self.name)
end

aclass = AClass:create("A. Class")
aclass:write()
```

Comment: Is that call literally supposed to be supported or is there an alternative syntax for this (either implicit or explicit). Because without a hack of the sort you are indicating (which is possible but ugly and costly) I don't see how it would be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be exactly this syntax. I have "testfile", which should not be changed and that demands the given syntax. This part of the assignment (the first part was implementing the inheritance) was also marked as very hard. Thats why I thought there must be some sort of hack involved.

Comment: Another (terrible) option - if you get `nil`, use `debug.backtrace` to get the current source location, and read in the source file as text to find what the variable lookup was

Comment: The main problem is that the 'rvalues' are being fully evaluated when you're constructing your table like `{'MyClass', attribute = MyClass}`. If `MyClass` isn't defined when that happens, what `Class` sees is just `{'MyClass', attribute = nil}` which is indistinguishable from `{'MyClass'}`.

Comment: If you're allowed to modify the syntax to something like this instead `Class 'MyClass' {attribute = MyClass}` that'll ease implementation.

Comment: Can you post the 'testfile' and add it to your question for completeness?

Comment: The testfile is added, although I think that "testfile" is the wrong word, as it basically is just a list of `print`s. The final test, which gets published later, checks everything via `pcall` and only posts something when an error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MyClass` is just a lookup in the global table (`_G`), you *could* mess with its metatable's `__index` to return a newly-defined MyClass object (which you would later need to fill with the details).

However, while feasible, such an implementation is

- wildly unsafe, as you could end up with an undefined class (or worse, you may end up inadvertantly creating an infinite lookup loop. Trust me, I've been there)
- very hard to debug, as every `_G` lookup for a non-existing variable will now return a newly created class object instead of nil (this problem could somewhat be reduced by requiring that class names start with an uppercase character)

If you go that route, be sure to also override `__newindex`.

Comment: If I understand this correctly that would not fix the problem with `nil == unknown`, or would it? But I like the idea with the uppercase convention. That may do the trick for the check by my tutor. I don't see how this "recursive type" should work while supporting all `nil` checks. I'm curious what their solution will be. Thanks!

Comment: No, this approach will not fix `nil == unknown` – nor should it. Whenever you fetch `MyClass` from `_G`, you create a placeholder. On class creation, you first check if a placeholder is already there and fill it, otherwise directly create the class object.

Answer (score 3):

How about providing the argument in string form?

```
Class{'MyClass', attribute = 'MyClass'}
```

Detect strings inside the implementation of `Class` and process them with `_G[string]` *after* creating the class

Or alternatively, use a function to delay the lookup:

```
Class{'MyClass', attribute = function() return MyClass end}
```